# YUI Charts Styling

Tags: javascript, charts, colors, yui, transparent

Through my search for a open-source charting system, I found the YUI library. So here is the question. How can I make the x-axis and y-axis transparent.

> style:
>                 {
>                     border: {color: 0xD0D696, size: 1},
>                     font: {name: "Arial", size: 10, color: 0x559330},
>                     dataTip:
>                     {
>                         border: {color: 0x559330, size: 1},
>                         font: {name: "Arial", size: 13, color: 0x586b71}
>                     },
>                     xAxis:
>                     {
>                         **color: 0x559330**
>                     },
>                     yAxis:
>                     {
>                         **color: 0x559330**,
>                         majorTicks: {color: 0x2e434d, length: 4},
>                         minorTicks: {color: 0x2e434d, length: 2},
>                         majorGridLines: {size: 1, color: 0xF7ECBB}
>                     }
>                 }

The bolded text is what I want to change. I tried color: "transparent", but with no luck. I checked the docs briefly, but no reference to transparent backgrounds.

Comment: what do you mean by transparent? can you just set it to the same color as the background? or do you want something behind/below the flash object to show thru?

Comment: If I set it 0xFFFFFF ( the color of background) , it will cut my elements with value 0 .

Comment: can you post a complete example with data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the reference, you should set the size to 0.

```
xAxis: { size: 0 }, yAxis: { size: 0}
```

**size**
A numeric value that represents the thickness of the axis itself. A value of 0 will hide the axis (but not the labels).

See this and other settings [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/charts/)